# Adding Small Assets Increases Standalone Data Folder Size Exponentially

Tags: unity-game-engine

I added 33 mb worth of sprite assets (they are large character illustrations), so I would expect the data folder to increase proportionally. However, the size actually increases by 2 GB (6000% increase!) increasing total data size by over 500% too.

Doesn't make any sense to me. Is there a mistake with my import options? I use mip maps, bilinear/trilinear filters. Truecolor/ vs compressed doesn't change anything.

Additional info: It's like 10 files with 5-8 large sprites each. Another weird thing is that when it's compressed to a zip file the size collapses to 142mb (from like 2.3 GB). Which is weird because that's too big of a difference.
It's also very slow to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons why file sizes can get so big.

As @zambari said, PNG/JPEG are compressed forms, which compress much better than what unity will. Due to that, you have to be careful with your file sizes, since they will be much bigger in-game.

Another issue I had was that my files weren't sized properly. The compression method that I was trying to utilize requires file sizes divisible by 4 (DTX5).

Another big issue was I had large images that I did not need. I used "generate mip-maps"  + trilinear filtering, and that once again doubled the file sizes. The best thing you can do is just use image sizes that reflect their use. Relying on Unity to do that for you by using max image size does not guarantee good quality (in fact it looked terrible). This was all in Unity 5

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is related to how unity handles image compression. The assets live in your project in compressed (jpg/png) form, but they get recompressed (or not) to a form thats fastest to decode on the target platform. Try playing with the compession settings with the asset import settings (available if you highlight your asset in the project window)

[image]